Unity, Have trouble with a bug
When I try to move a block along a certain vector3, it does not move it. At the same time, the error check does not work, and the debugger does not complain and says that everything is fine. What could be the mistake? Or is there something wrong with Unity?
I am writing in C#, Visual Studio 2022 editor, the latest version of Unity.
Heres Code:
using UnityEngine; 

public class BlockController : MonoBehaviour 
{ 
    public GameObject block; // Объект, тени которого нужно отключить 
    public Transform trans; 
    void Start() 
    { 
        trans.position = new Vector3(10, 10, 10); 
        if (block.GetComponent<Transform>().position != new Vector3(10, 10, 10)) 
        { 
            Debug.LogError("Возможно, чисто теоретически, он не видит блок"); 
        } 
        Debug.Log("Чекай результат"); 
    } 
}

Tried to Ask some AI and tried to rewrite code, didnt worked

firstly, block doesnt need you to get the transform  component to get position, block.transform.position will get that, secondly, you may suffer from floating point issues, lastly, there is nothing here that moves the block, the block position is never altered.

Please use a more descriptive title! I guess around 99% of people come here because they Have trouble with a bug ... Tried to Ask some AI and tried to rewrite code, didnt worked we don't even know what exactly you are trying to achieve

How are trans and block related? Why move one and then check for the other?

@BugFinder the approximate equality for Vector3 == operator Shou cover the floating point issues

@derHugo block refers to trans. The "Cube" object is stored in the block, but I used trans in order not to write unnecessary "Blocks.GetComponent<>..."
before that, everything worked well, although I changed the code only by adding the "Light" object (I eventually deleted it), but after deleting the Light, the code stopped working at all.
